# Regex to remove ' from media:credit in yahoo pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I hope this is really simple - but I haven't been able to find the answer.  I'm using Yahoo Pipes to output an instagram RSS feed as JSON.  Everything works fine except when the photographer's name (in the item [media:credit].content field) ends with a '.  That breaks the javascript I'm using to display the JSON content.

Can someone suggest the appropriate regex to put into the Pipes module to remove the ' from the person's name?

Thanks

Comment: /'/s
That will match all apostrophes in a string. Not sure how Y!Pipes implements this though...

Answer (score 0):

Search for the following regexp.

`(.+?)'?` and replace it with `/1`